# How to use both causative and て欲しい grammar at the same time?

Tags: grammar, causation

I want to say the following in Japanese.

> I want the police officer to make the dog bite the snatcher.

My attempt is as follows.

> 私は警察官に犬にひったくりを噛ませて欲しい。

Is it correct? Is it possible to use just one に?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[私]{わたし}は[警察官]{けいさつかん}**に**[犬]{いぬ}**に**ひったくりを[噛]{か}ませて[欲]{ほ}しい。」

is correct if I have to choose between "correct" and "incorrect".

A little more natural-sounding word order IMHO would be:

> 「私は警察官**に**、ひったくりを**犬に**噛ませて欲しい。」

for clarity reasons.  Cramming the phrase 「A**に**B**に**」 into the same part of a sentence is not such a great idea even though it is still grammatical.

Finally, if you used 「噛み[付]{つ}かせて」 instead of 「噛ませて」, it would be even more natural.

Comment: 私は彼女に、彼女と私に結婚させて欲しいい。Does it sound natural?

Comment: To me, not really.  I could only "guess" what you mean by that.   When we use the phrase 「結婚させてほしい」 in Japanese, we are always referring to a third person, such as a parent, allowing or not allowing you to marry someone.

Comment: @Yasashii It doesn't make sense.