# How to use nested causative?

Tags: grammar, causation

I want to exaggerate [my previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/31024/11192) by nesting one more causative action. Assume that there are a policeman, a girl with her dog, and a snatcher on the street. The dog belongs to the girl.

## Question

How do I express the following sentence in Japanese? Is my sentence below correct?

> I want the policeman to make the girl make her dog bite the snatcher.
>
> ひったくりを犬に噛みつかせる
>
> ------- ことを女の子にさせて
>
> ------------ ほしい警察官に私は。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting ～させる is not really common:

> - (1) 少女は犬をひったくりに噛みつかせる。 (OK, simple)
> - (2) (?) 警察官は少女に犬をひったくりに噛みつかせさせる。 (may not be wrong, but very hard to understand)
> - (3) (*) 私は警察官に少女に犬をひったくりに噛みつかせさせさせたい。 (almost gibberish)

An easy and natural way is to use **～するよう(に)** (≒"so that ～") and say like this:

> - (4) 少女が犬をひったくりに噛みつかせるよう、警察官に言わせたい。
> - (5) 私は警察官に、少女に犬をひったくりに噛みつかせるよう言ってほしい。
> - (6) 少女の犬がひったくりに噛みつくよう、警察官に言って欲しい。
>     (using no causative せる/させる at all. It's obvious that 警察官 is saying something not the 犬 but to the 少女, so this should be enough)

It's much harder for me to translate this without using よう.

> - (7) (?) 私は警察官に、少女に犬にひったくりを噛みつかせさせて欲しい。
>     (using (2) above, but even harder to understand)
> - (8) (?) 私は警察官に、少女に犬にひったくりを噛みつかせることをさせて欲しい。

The last one is the closest to your translation attempt, but ～ことをさせる isn't not common in the first place.

Note that [～て欲しい can be used only for the speaker's own desire](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2524/5010).

Comment: @優しいエイリアン Yes. The "causee" is marked with を, because 噛みつく is an intransitive verb which happens to take に. [General rule here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33515/5010). ひったくりを犬に噛みつかせる means "to make the snatcher bite the dog".

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/44885/meaning/m2u/ 噛む is transitive (eg, ガムを噛む), but 噛みつく is always intransitive. Thus, 「犬をひったくりに噛みつかせる」 is roughly the same as 「犬にひったくりを噛ませる」. I understand it's confusing... The same can be said with 抱く(vt)/抱きつく(vi), 追う(vt)/追いつく(vi), 食らう(vt)/食らいつく(vi), etc.